# Interfacing two java classes

Tags: java

Im trying to interface two classes in the same program, but Im having problems.
I have a Describe class that contains the main and reads in/out all the info.

```
    public class Describe{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int side1, side2, side3;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Describe tri1 = new Describe();

    System.out.println("Enter an integer dimension for " +
            " side a of triangle 1: ");
    side1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter an integer dimension for " +
            " side b of triangle 1: ");
    side2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter an integer dimension for " +
            " side c of triangle 1: ");
    side3 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Triangle 1 has sides of: ");
    System.out.println("side a: " + tri1.getside1());//This is where the 
    error is
```

It keeps giving me an error when I try to call the methods saying that it cannot find symbol, but I'm not sure why. This is the beginning of the other class

```
    public class Triangle extends Describe{
    private int side1;
    private int side2;
    private int side3;
    public int accumulator = 0;
    public int count = 0;
    public int perim = 0;
    public Triangle(int side1, int side2, int side3)
    {
     if (isValid(side1, side2, side3 )== true)
         accumulator = addTotalPerim();
     else 
        {
            side1 = 1; side2 = 1; side3 = 1;
        }
        count ++;            
    }
    public int getSide1()
    {
        return side1;
    }
    public int getSide2()
    {
        return side2;
    }
    public int getSide3()
    {
        return side3;
    }
```

Comment: `Describe` does not define a `getSide1` method.  `tri1` also has nothing to do with `Triangle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never pass your side values into your constructor upon creating your Triangle object. You also make no reference to you subclass `Triangle`.

```
Triangle tri = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
```

If you truly wanted to extend your describe class you'd need to call super() somewhere inside the Triangle constructor and handle it from there.

Comment: Thanks its running now but all my answers keep returning back 0

Comment: Is Triangle really a type of Describe? It seems the two types are not really related, and maybe inheritance is confusing things here?

Answer (score 0):

Can't help much without your specific error but what I can see however is that

1.
`Describe tri1 = new Describe();`
should be an instance of the class `Triangle` sense `getside1()` is in the `Triangle` class. `tri1.getside1()` gives you error because there is no function `getside1()` in class Describe.

2.`tri1.getside1()` should be `tri1.getSide1()`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("side a: " + tri1.getside1());
```

Java methods are case-sensitive.

```
System.out.println("side a: " + tri1.getSide1());
```

And you should create a `Triangle` instance for `tri1`